# Spliting a string between two special characters

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split a string between two special characters. here is my string

```
 https://localhost:8080/app/EmailActivation&email=karthi622@gmail.com&hash=8be935b6-4f58-425f-a45d-f51ba9f67249
```

I want only two strings that are email and hash. My output would be like

```
 karthi622@gmail.com
 8be935b6-4f58-425f-a45d-f51ba9f67249
```

Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: This is a good use for regular expressions.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the code below:

```
String str = new String("https://localhost:8080/app/EmailActivation&email=karthi622@gmail.com&hash=8be935b6-4f58-425f-a45d-f51ba9f67249");
String email = new String(str.split("&")[1].replace("email=", ""));
System.out.println(email);
String hash = new String(str.split("&")[2].replace("hash=", ""));
System.out.println(hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String in = " https://localhost:8080/app/EmailActivation&email=karthi622@gmail.com&hash=8be935b6-4f58-425f-a45d-f51ba9f67249";
    String temp = in.substring(in.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String params[] = temp.split("&");
    String email = params[1].substring(params[1].indexOf("=") + 1);
    System.out.println(email);
    String hash = params[2].substring(params[2].indexOf("=") + 1);
    System.out.println(hash);
```

Answer (score -1):

String in="https://localhost:8080/app/EmailActivation&email=karthi622@gmail.com&hash=8be935b6-4f58-425f-a45d-f51ba9f67249";

```
        if(in.contains("email")&&in.contains("hash"))
        {
            String email = in.substring(in.indexOf("email=")+("email=").length(),in.lastIndexOf("&"));
            String hash = in.substring(in.indexOf("hash=")+("hash=").length(),in.length());
            System.out.println("email :"+email+" hash :"+hash);
        }
```